# React typescript FC vs Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-tsx

I am using react with typescript. What is the difference between `FC` vs `Component`?

Which is best practice?

Use cases for each?

Does `Component` is deprecated since react latest version with hooks is not using classes?

Comment: Agreed with @boop_the_snoot. FC doesn't have a state it can't maintain itself, but a class based can control itself and all its child components. Advanced concepts include React hooks. But first have an understanding of react components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## "old" react (< v16.8) vs "new" react (>= v.16.8)

(following is just my MHO)

"Old" react is not deprecated yet and react team is also not planning to remove class components in near future. But in general using react hooks is highly recommended by react developers. Also it is a more functional approach, which might be good or bad for you depending on your experience. (btw i prefer functional programming)

#### State

- old: only class components can maintain state
- new: functional components can also maintain state (`useState` hook). Also it's much easier to share stateful logic accross very different components

#### Lifecycle methods

- old: only class components can declare lifecycle methods
- new: functional components can also react on lifecycle events (`useEffect` hook)

#### Context API

- old: IMHO a bit clunky and confusing
- new: IMHO much cleaner and easier to use (`useContext` hook)

This are just the **main differences** for more details see [here](https://reactjs.org/blog/2019/02/06/react-v16.8.0.html).